# Galois group acts transitively on the roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $p(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$. Let $K$ be a splitting field of $f(x)$.
Let $R:=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2, \alpha_3,\dots,\alpha_k\}$ be the set of all roots of $p(x)$ in $K$. Then, it is easy to check that 
\begin{align*}
    \varphi_1:F(\alpha_1) &\to  F(\alpha_2)\subseteq K \\
    \alpha_1 & \to \alpha_2
\end{align*} 
is an $F$-isomorphism i.e. bijective ring homomorphism with $\varphi_1(x)=x$ for all $x\in F$.

Now, I want to extend the map $\varphi_1$ to an $F$-homomorphism 
\begin{align*}
\varphi_2: F(\alpha_1)(\alpha_2)\to K
\end{align*}
Clearly, if such an extension $\varphi_2$
exists then it is determined by $\varphi_2(\alpha_2)$, and $\varphi_2(\alpha_2)$ must belong to $R$.

**Question**. How do we guarantee that such an extension $\varphi_2$ exist?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $h(t) \in F(\alpha_1)[t]$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_2$ over $F(\alpha_1)$, apply $\varphi_1$ to the coefficients of $h$ to obtain $h^{\varphi_1}(t) \in \varphi_1(F(\alpha_1))[t]$, set $\varphi_2(\alpha_2) = \beta_2$ for any root $\beta_2 \in K$ of $h^{\varphi_1}(t)$.

$\beta_2 $ always exists because $K/F$ is normal. Continuing this way you'll have $\varphi_k \in Aut(K/F)$.